# How to hide next/preivous button of MonthCalendar control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, button, monthcalendar

I have a project and i want to hide next/preivous button of MonthCalendar control in C#. I have searched Google but i can't find the solution. Please show me.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable them by setting the control's MinDate and MaxDate properties, programmatically set MinDate to day 1 of this month, and MaxDate to whatever the last day of this month is.

Comment: I never knew that this might be possible. Thanks @Wanabrutbeer once again :)

Comment: +1 that works but is a little unintuitive. When you cant click the arrows you can still click the Mopnth name and it will show you the single Month and if you click again the single year. It might be better to have a label control with the month name covering the arrows and Month.

Comment: No problem :) I don't think its a perfect solution, but it will work. The only other way is to create a custom control that extends MonthCalendar, and override the OnPaint() method, and tweak its presentation, but I'm not as well versed in this. It may also require overrides of other methods, such as OnSizeChanged, or other layout type events.

Comment: @Wanabrutbeer or you could extend an object such as Panel on the MonthCalendar header, simple :D

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to add the Hours, Minutes and Seconds... Especially useful for avoiding exceptions on MaxDate.

```
DateTime firstDayInMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime lastDayInMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month), 23, 59, 59);

yourCalendar.MinDate = firstDayInMonth;
yourCalendar.MaxDate = lastDayInMonth;
```